# How to create a class within a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

Hello I really am having a hard time explaining what I want but I can show you to the best ability what I desire programmatically

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self, arg, arg2):
        self.arg = arg
        self.Foo = arg2

    def print_stuff(self):
        print(self.arg, self.Foo)



class C2:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.Foo = "bar"
        self.C1 = C1(arg, self.Foo)
    
inst = C2("test")
inst.C1.print_stuff()
```

I basically want the `inst.C1.print_stuff()` to look the same, but I was wondering if there was a better way of implementing.

Here's an incorrect way of writing it just so you can get a better idea of what i'm going for.

```
# Invalid code below
class C2:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.Foo = "Bar"


    class C1:
        def print_stuff(self):
            print(self.arg, self.Foo)
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: It looks like you might want `C2` to inherit `C1`, if you understand what that means.

Comment: There is usually never any need to nest classes.

Comment: I want to specifically be able to type `inst.C1.print_stuff()` just to organize better, I could inherit, but then I would be able to do `inst.print_stuff()` & not `inst.C1.print_stuff()` to invoke the method

Comment: That sounds like a bad practice one way or another. If you're ok with this, then the first code is ok. Apart from that, you can explain your real problem and we might suggest something better.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych this is the best example I can give, I want to do something like `Car.Wheels.Steer()` and have it look like that instead of just `Car.Steer()`

Comment: if you have a better way of doing this I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just doing it:

```
class C2:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.Foo = "Bar"
        self.C1 = self.C1(arg, self.Foo)

    class C1:
        def __init__(self, arg, arg2):
            self.arg = arg
            self.Foo = arg2

        def print_stuff(self):
            print(self.arg, self.Foo)


inst = C2("test")
inst.C1.print_stuff()  # -> test Bar

inst2 = C2("test2")
inst2.C1.print_stuff()  # -> test2 Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `C1` as `class C1(C2):`

This will create an inheritance link with C1 the subclass of C2

Thus, you can do `inst.print_stuff()` directly

Comment: I specifically want to do `inst.C1.print_stuff()` though